# How does carrierwave change files name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I uploaded some files and thier names were changed like this

```
MY_FILE (1).jpg  =>  MY_FILE__1_.jpg
MY_FILE (1) (1).jpg  =>  MY_FILE__1___1_.jpg
MY_FILE_(1).jpg  =>  MY_FILE__1_.jpg
MY_FILE_(1) (copy).jpg  =>  MY_FILE__1___copy_.jpg
MY_FILE-(1).jpg  =>  MY_FILE-_1_.jpg
```

it's creating problem for me, because I'm saving file using ajax and checking filename in response. but filename from response does not match with my uploaded file. Because carrierwave changed it.

I wants to know which regular expression they are using to change filename.
I check in the gem but I'm not sure where to look.